# how can update to google map api version 3 in drupal 6

Tags: google-maps, drupal, drupal-gmap

In my drupal site, I have installed the gmap module. But that is in version 2.115. Now I got a mail from google that update the google API version. I have generated the API key version 3. But no idea about implementing them to the module files. 
drupal_set_html_head(' $query))) .'" type="text/javascript">');

This I changed to 
drupal_set_html_head('');

Also in gmap.js 
obj.map = new GMap2(elem, obj.opts); changed to obj.map = new google.maps.Map(elem, obj.opts);

But after adding this, Javascript is required to view this map. is showing.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/818638) on d.org. There are several patches and solutions.